# How do I use Itemadd event for multiple folders?

Tags: outlook

I would like to add the ItemAdd event to multiple folders. The difficulty that I had is the the number of folders is not fixed, but they are all sub-folders of a main folder.

Answer (score 1):

Create a list that will hold Items objects (List), set up the event handler on each Items object, add them to the list to make sure they stay referenced.